# Safari for Mac ignoring HTML5 download filename

Tags: javascript, html, safari

I have a map web app and want to be able to save route data in a GPX file.  To do this I am generating an anchor tag containing the data and using the HTML5 download property to set the file name.  This works as expected on OS X (10.9.4) in both Firefox (29.0.1) and Chrome (37.0.2062.94), but in Safari (7.0.6) it is ignoring the name in the download attribute and saving a file called simply "Unknown".

This is the link in my HTML file:

```
<a href="#" id="map_save">Save to GPX</a>
```

In this is how it is linked up in my Javascript file (using jQuery):

```
function exportToGPX( gpxData ) {

    gpxData = 'data:application/gpx+xml;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent( gpxData );
    $( '#map_save' ).attr( { 'href': gpxData ,'download': 'myfile.gpx' } );

}

$( document ).ready( function() {

    $( '#map_save' ).click( function( event ) {
        exportToGPX.apply();
    } );

} );
```

Everything I have seen suggests that Safari should honour this attribute, and it is presumably not a WebKit issue if it works in Chrome.  Using the Web Inspector to view the DOM Tree shows the attribute is correctly applied:

```
<a href=​"data:​application/​gpx+xml;​ch…09%3C%2Ftrk%3E%0A%3C%2Fgpx%3E" id=​"map_save" download=​"myfile.gpx">​Save to GPX​</a>​
```

As I say, it does download the file, just without giving it a proper name.  Is there anything I am doing wrong or need to also do to make this work properly in Safari?

Comment: In case anyone else is wondering the same, it seems I was mislead about Safari.  According to http://caniuse.com/#feat=download it has never been supported.

Comment: Happen to find a solution for this? I'm facing same problem now.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have just taken it as something Safari does not fully support it so learned to accept the annoying "Unknown" file names.

Comment: Actually I observed that it works fine if I set the download attribute together with the href while making the element 'a' - strange, - but once I assign a new href through JS, it breaks again!

Comment: Do you mean hard coding the link in the HTML?  It does not work if I create an entirely new element in JS (e.g. `node = document.CreateElement('a');node.setAttribute( 'download','name'),node.href='data:...';parent.appendChild(node);node.click();`).  It still ignores the name I set.

Comment: yes, I have a python code generating the report in html format. when the download attribute is hardcoded in html part, safari is using correct file name while downloading it. the moment I change the href (though js), it does not work any more. like you said, creating the 'a' from JS also does not honor the file name. I feel this may be a bug in the setAttribute!

Comment: If I chose 'download linked file as..' - it is able to show correct name as default. I can live with that for now. Please do post if you found something in future. cheers